# Rails 3.2.11 Nodejs symbol lookup error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, node.js

I recently updated from Rails 3.2.8 to 3.2.11 for the major security patches...though I'm not exactly sure if that is directly related to my issue. I have a production setup with passenger/apache and get the following when trying to access the app:

```
    ActionView::Template::Error (nodejs: symbol lookup error: nodejs: undefined symbol: _ZN2v82V837AdjustAmountOfExternalAllocatedMemoryEi

    (in /home/cb/public_html/production/app/assets/javascripts/admin.js.coffee)):
    4:   <title>cb</title>
    5:   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial|Poiret+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    6:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    7:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    8:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    9: </head>
    10: <body id="main">
    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2747373451058239248_18220480'
```

It says that the symbol is referenced in admin.js.coffee but this file has no code in it... only the default comments when it's generated with a controller.

I have another rails app on this server still running 3.2.8 with almost the exact same gems with no issues. This error only appears when running on the production server (CentOS 6.2, NodeJS v0.6.18)

Comment: My temporary workaround was to disable the asset pipeline and move/rename all of the assets to the pre-pipeline form. This avoids nodejs and prevents the error...definitely annoying to have to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. I'm not exactly sure what the difference is, but upgrading nodejs to the latest version (v0.8.19) did the trick for me. I had previously installed node with the yum repository, but it seems the package maintainer hasn't updated in a while. So, here's what I did:

`yum remove nodejs`

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.19/node-v0.8.19.tar.gz
tar zxvf node-v0.8.19.tar.gz
cd node-v0.8.19
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install
```